# Does source compatibility always imply binary compatibility?

Tags: java

Say I compile my classes against `lib_v1.0.jar` and distribute my binaries. Then I update to `lib_v1.1.jar`. Assuming that my source code compiles against v1.1 without errors, will my old distributed binaries always work with `lib_v1.1.jar` or do I have to recompile and redistribute new binaries?

I read over https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html but could not find a clear or explicit answer to my question.

Comment: If lib_v1.1.jar is backwards compatible (maintaining all old API), and seeing only the minor version is changed from 0 to 1, then there is not problem. The possible use of newer API of course ensuring your next deployment uses the new lib_v1.1.jar. The implementation of old functions may slightly differ though.

Comment: Compiles is not the same as runs. Who knows if there are breaking changes or deprecations. Usually I would fix the compile errors first, then try and run the thing (which usually involves fixing some wiring errors on startup), and then regression test to check for other impacts.

Comment: "work" is a very vague term. Assume you're calling `getThirdPartyThing().doSomething();`. This will work, unless in 1.1, the method returns `null`. There are certainly many more caveats and details to consider, though. (And one should make clear that there are **no** nasty reflection tricks involved - these can break everything, of course...)

Comment: To clarify, by "works" and "compatible", I mean the guarantee that there are no (new) linker errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source compatibility does not imply binary compatibility.

For example, we have following interface in library:

```
// jar v1.0 
interface Service {
   int calculate(); // signature: ()I
}
```

An we call it from our code:

```
Service service = ...
int a = service.calculate(); // calls calculate()I method
```

In version v1.1 library code was slightly changed:

```
// jar v1.1 
interface Service {
   Integer calculate(); // signature: ()Ljava.lang.Integer;
}
```

Source code is still compatible, thanks to autoboxing, but if we run our code with new library version it will fail with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Service.calculate()I error.

Similar issues can be caused by lambda scopes, generics cast, implicit type casts etc.

Comment: Nice, I didnt think about that. Have my upvote for that!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the clear and concise example!

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming that my source code compiles against v1.1 without errors, will my old distributed binaries always work

You should be relatively safe, as long as your code doesn't use reflection, for example to instantiate classes by name, or really bad, access private fields through the "back door". As, of course: reflection happens all at runtime, so "my code that uses reflection still compiles" doesn't help you a bit. Or as seen, as long as the changes in the 3rd party API aren't about signature changes that a compiler will gracefully ignore, such as turning int into Integer, as outlined in the other answer.

Having said that: the real problem isn't "it compiles". The real problem is: does it still *behave* as expected?

And that question can't be answered by compiling.

So let's enhance your statement:

> Assuming that my source code compiles against v1.1 without errors, and that all my unit and integration tests that I wrote to ensure that my code can properly that 3rd party library all pass when running against v1.1 of ...

Then you can be pretty safe. Unless you forgot some important test case.

But basically you have then a similar confidence about the quality of your product, no matter if your product uses v1.0 or v1.1. Because even when using v1.0, it could still happen to you that tomorrow comes in a bug report about a problem that you haven't seen before, simply because it happens so rarely.

Comment: I think that the question aimed at things like whether a `NoSuchMethodError` could suddenly be thrown even though it seemed to compile properly (this specific case cannot happen, but I think ~"something like this" was meant - the question may simply not be clear enough ...)

Comment: @Marco13 is correct. I want to know if I am safe from (new) linker errors. I realize the new library version may be a buggy mess, but that's not the issue I'm concerned about right now.

Comment: @BalzGuenat I appreciate the quick accept, and I improved the answer a bit to be clear about that linkage part.

Comment: I'll explain a bit why I care more about linking than actual behavior: My software has to integrate with different versions of another software. That software may change the interface I integrate against, but always in a source-backwards-compatible matter. I am now wondering if I need to build a separate artifact for each of the other software's versions or if it's fine if I just compile against the oldest supported version. As I understand your answer, the latter should work, correct?

Comment: See @Viktors answer below for an example where this assumption is not true.

Comment: @BalzGuenat It should work ... while you do exactly that. But well: we are talking about you releasing your product, don't we. And I think when you release your product, you build against the version of the 3rd party you release your stuff with. Meaning: what comes into play here is also versioning of your build setup, and such things.

Comment: @BalzGuenat And ouch, that other answer is correct. So feel free to move the accept to the counter example answer!

Answer (score 1):

It should work if the target jdk of the library is compatible with the target jdk used for compiling your classes assuming there a no breaking changes in the new library.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.  Use of a changed constant will not be correct.

Consider this constant field in the library:

```
package com.example.lib;

public class LibConstants {
    public static final int MAX_THREADS = 8;
}
```

The Java compiler replaces constants *at compile time.*  If your code looks like this:

```
someLibClass.startServer(LibConstants.MAX_THREADS);
```

Java will compile it as:

```
someLibClass.startServer(8);
```

If a later version of the library changes the constant:

```
public class LibConstants {
    public static final int MAX_THREADS = 20;
}
```

Your code *will not* use the new value of the constant, because the compiler removed any reference to the static field when the code was compiled.